# Criar Script de looping de uma função

Tags: python, chat

sou bem iniciante no Python. Estou com um projeto de criar um chat UDP em Python. Quero resolver uma issue de criar uma mensagem de Online. Digitei o código só que está dando erro.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
#coding:utf-8

from twisted.internet.task import LoopingCall
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.protocol import DatagramProtocol

def mensagem_presenca():
    print("Estou Online!!")

class Client(DatagramProtocol):
    def sendMessage(self, data, host, port):
        self.transport.write(data, host, port)


lc = LoopingCall(sendMessage("teste", localhost, 8888))
lc.start(30.0)


reactor.run()
```

---

> luiz@luiz:~$ python teste_timer.py  Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "teste_timer.py", line 16, in 
>       lc = LoopingCall(sendMessage("teste", localhost, 8888)) NameError: name 'sendMessage' is not defined luiz@luiz:~$

---

O que pode ser?

Comment: Você definiu `sendMessage` como um método da classe `Client`, não como uma função, então precisa instanciar a classe antes.

Comment: obrigado. Já instanciei a classe. Agora está dando outro erro:
def mensagem_presenca():
    print("Estou Online!!")

class Client(DatagramProtocol):
 def sendMessage(self, data, host, port):
  self.transport.write(data, host, port)


lc = LoopingCall(Client.sendMessage("teste", '127.0.0.1', 8888))
lc.start(30.0)


reactor.run()

-----
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "teste_timer.py", line 16, in <module>
    lc = LoopingCall(Client.sendMessage("teste", '127.0.0.1', 8888))
TypeError: sendMessage() missing 1 required positional argument: 'port'

Comment: Eu já coloquei a porta. Mas ele está reclamando dizendo que não coloquei.

Comment: Pelo visto eu tenho que colocar um valor no lugar do self. O que coloco?

Comment: Parece que ainda lhe falha bastante os conceitos básicos da programação. Você sabe o que é criar uma instância de uma classe?

Comment: Sim. Eu to vendo aqui e acho que o problema é que eu chamei um método da classe e não da instância dela. É isso?

Comment: Exato. E quando você chama o método da instância, o `self` é passado implicitamente.

Answer (score -1):

`sendMessage` é um método de `Client`, logo, é preciso instanciar a classe antes.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
#coding:utf-8

from twisted.internet.task import LoopingCall
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.protocol import DatagramProtocol

def mensagem_presenca():
    print("Estou Online!!")

class Client(DatagramProtocol):
    def sendMessage(self, data, host, port):
        self.transport.write(data, host, port)


client = Client()
lc = LoopingCall(client.sendMessage("teste", localhost, 8888))
lc.start(30.0)


reactor.run()
```

A única coisa que não entendi é qual o papel que você pretende dar para a função `mensagem_presenca`, pois atualmente ela somente imprime essa mensagem no console do desenvolvedor, mas sinta-se a vontade para fazer mais perguntas, caso precise.